# 404 when WebSecurityConfig is present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1**

**spring-boot-starter-security**

```
package ru.pcask.securing.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

This was copied from an official tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

**The problem:**

When I comment every line in his config file out, it shows a Spring security login page. The very login form that is out of the box, made using Bootstrap.

[image]

But when I uncomment this code and am redirected to http://localhost:8080/login, this error appears:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Dec 30 19:50:40 MSK 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

What can I try next to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is here in this line of code, you want every request to be authenticated.

```
anyRequest().authenticated()
```

if you would like to white list some links or all, you can add them explicitly, this is extremely important to add before above call

```
.anyMatchers("/**").permitAll() // whitelists all 
.anyMatchers("/pages/**").permitAll() // whitelists /pages/...

.anyRequest().authenticated()
```